# how to print a tablelayoutpanel to printer

Tags: c#, printing, tablelayout

I am working on an application that will display data onto the table layout when button is clicked, there will labels in that table layout,  after the data had been displayed,  user will click a print button that will print all the contents in that specific table layout.

I know that i can use drawtobitmap, but I don't know what is the next step. I don't need to prview before printing, and it can be using print dialog or not.

Thanks

Comment: __No!__ do not use `DrawToBitmap` as it will only get you the screen resolution and therefore will look __terrible__ in print. You need to code the `PrintPage` event and there just as you would do in a `Paint` event you need to write out each part of the content in a suitable way using the `Graphics.Drawxxx` methods. More work but good quality! Search for a 'c# printing tutorial'  !

Comment: Is there any link that u can show me?  I actually got the darwtobitmap working but the resolution is kinda weird like u said. Also, I know that u can use Papersize to change the size of the page,  however, I could not get the proper size still. I would like to print it out as half of a letter size,  so 8.5" x 5.5"

Comment: Also, I have my paper size set to my actual paper size which is 8.5" x5.5" but my bitmap is abit bigger than the actual paper size, which means I cant see everything on the table layout on the actual paper,how can I change it so that he bitmap fit the paper size ?

Comment: Put this 'user:3152130 printpage' into the search field right here at the top right and study the five posts that come up! - To change the Dpi of a given bmp use `Bitmap.SetResolution()`